# React Redux render connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using the `connect` function React Redux to connect my store to a React component. After it is connected I want to render the component. This works:

```
class Init extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View /> // Is really more elaborate
    )
  }
}
```

Connect it to the store:

```
const InitPage = connect(
  state => ({
  }),
  dispatch => ({
  })
)(Init)
```

Now render it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const content = <InitPage />

    return (
      {content}
    )
  }
}
```

Great. This all works. However...

When I place the `connect` inside a function and return the connect, as in:

```
const getInitPage = () => {
  const InitPage = connect(
    state => ({
    }),
    dispatch => ({
    })
  )(Init)

  return InitPage
}
```

If I now try to render the component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const content = getInitPage()

    return (
      {content}
    )
  }
}
```

I get an error:

```
Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

What is the correct way to return a Redux "connected" component from a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are returning the component from the function, you need to render it like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const Content = getInitPage()

    return (
      <Content/>
    )
  }
}
```

Also make sure the componentName starts with a uppercase character.